# Add array to URL string

Tags: apache-flex, webview, adobe

I know this questions is going to have an easy obvious answer but i have spent over two days now trying to do it with no luck (I am a Flex newbie)
Basically i am trying to open a webView that will open google maps to the location in an array

The location comes from data in an array taken from facebook events (that works fine and will display the data) but i am struggling with passing this information to the webView.loadURL string

The data i want in the array is 'data.location' (the code i am having issues with is in the itemrenderer towards the bottom of the code snippet)

I have tried so many different options i am now stuck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="Home" creationComplete="onLoad()">
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    [Bindable] private var facebookEvents:ArrayCollection;
    import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;
    private function onLoad():void
    {
        if(FacebookMobile.getSession() != null) {
            getEvents()
        } else {
            eventsDataGrid.visible=false
            NotLogin.visible=true
        }

    }

    private function getEvents():void {
        var fql:String = "select name, location, pic, start_time from event where creator = 148839887036 and eid in (select eid from event_member where uid=148839887036)";
        FacebookMobile.fqlQuery(fql, handleGetEventsResponse);
    }

    private function handleGetEventsResponse(events:Object, fail:Object):void {
        if (events != null)
            facebookEvents = new ArrayCollection(events as Array);
        //else
            //status = "Error";
    }   
]]>
</fx:Script>

    <s:List id="eventsDataGrid" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{facebookEvents}">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:ItemRenderer>
                    <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import com.facebook.graph.utils.FacebookDataUtils;
                            var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView
                            var mapURL:String = ('http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr='+ "{data.location}")
                            private function time2DateStr(time:String):String {
                                return FacebookDataUtils.stringToDate(time).toLocaleString();
                            }

                            protected function getDirections_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                            {
                                webView.stage = this.stage;
                                webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 100, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
                                webView.loadURL(mapURL);    
                            }

                        ]]>
                    </fx:Script>
                    <s:HGroup paddingBottom="10" paddingTop="10">
                        <s:Image source="{data.pic}"/>
                        <s:VGroup width="100%">
                            <s:Label text="{data.name}" fontWeight="bold" width="100%"/>
                            <s:Label text="Where: {data.location}"/>
                            <s:Label text="When: {time2DateStr(data.start_time)}"/>
                            <s:Label text="Get Directions" click="getDirections_clickHandler(event)" id="getDirections"/>
                        </s:VGroup>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:ItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
        </s:List>
    <s:Label visible="false" x="6" id="NotLogin" width="463" height="78" styleName="text"
             text="Sorry You Need To Be Logged In Via Facebook, Please Go Back and Log In, THANK YOU"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

all i needed to do was to add the data into the brackets (dont know the offical name) here it is

```
protected function directions_click (location:String):void
                                {
                                    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=' + location));
                                }
```

and for the button/ label

```
<s:Label text="Get Directions" fontFamily="lucida grande" fontSize="14" color="#3b5998" click="directions_click(data.location)"/>
```